# How to import project from Oracle JDeveloper to NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, jdeveloper

Question stands for itself. How to import project from JDeveloper 10.1.3.5.0 to NetBeans 8. If it is of any metter it is a java webaplicaton.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans has the option to create Web project from source - https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/project-setup.html?print=yes#existing-web-sources

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can help but Jdeveloper can migrate de code from Netbeans. Officially there's a video about it.

http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/NBtoJDevProject/NBtoJDevProject.html